# Conditional Formatting Not working (maybe pilot error?)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, highlighting

Excel Version 16.68.

I want to compare numbers in Column **D** to a Reference Number and use Conditional Formatting Formulas in Column **E** to highlight the corresponding cells.

I use Formulas because the highlight color is different for each cell in Column **E**, depending on the evaluation of the corresponding cell in Column **D**.

Example: **=D3>$m$5** should highlight Column E3 Red with Dark Red Text.

Problem: **no formatting** is taking place. (could be pilot error; I'm just not seeing it)

Answer (score 0):

In my sample I formated D2:D15 and use the formula:

```
=D2>$M$5
```

[image]